# How to equal button text with the addition of two button text

Tags: android

How to equal button text with the addition of two button text?

I have tried the following codes

```
String button1Text = button1.getText().toString();
String button2Text = button2.getText().toString();
String button3Text = button3.getText().toString();

if((button1Text + button2Text).equals(button3Text))

//I have also tried
if((button1Text.concat( button2Text)).equals(button3Text))
```

It doesn't work. The if is not executed. Please help.

Comment: 1) read how to post a question.. 2) what is your goal? You have to check if they are equals? which are the text of the 3 buttons?

Comment: are they same case? which part not working. Have you tried equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: your code is working fine

Comment: What is your issue? What are the values of `button1Text`, `button2Text` and `button3Text`?

Comment: btw probably since it's not working consider that the texts are not equals... just to say

Comment: button1Text value is 2 button2Text value is 3 but when i add or concatenate it is equal to 23 not 5.button3Text value is 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks right, I think. Maybe you could try the following:

```
String btn12 = button1Text + button2Text;
if(btn12.equals(button3Text)) {
    return true;
}
```

For debug purposes you could log buttonText1, buttonText2, buttonText3 and the concat string btn12. Do they really have the same content?

**Update:**

Ahh okay the strings contains numbers and you want to add the numbers. Then try the following:

```
String button1Text = "1";
        String button2Text = "2";
        String button3Text = "3";
        String number = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(button1Text) + Integer.parseInt(button2Text));

        if(number.equals(button3Text)) {
            Log.d("debug", "it's true");
        }
```

You have to cast the strings to integers first. Then you can add the numbers and convert back into string. Or you convert buttonText3 to int too and then compare both values with

```
if((number1 + number2) == number3)
```

Comment: button1 consists 2 and button2 consists 3 but btn12 is showing 23 instead of 5.

Comment: @Navyasri Glad that I was able to help. Please mark my answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

use concat() function to concatenate two string.

Comment: I have tried button1.concat(button2)).equals(button3)

Comment: first `String s= button1.concat(button2))` then compare with `if(s.equals(button3)`

Comment: if((button1Text.concat( button2Text)).equals(button3Text))